# Timer Job - targets to specific application server

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

Below is our server topology

3 WFEs
2 App Servers
1 DB server

Now, I would like to write a custom timer job that should run only on the specific application server("APP1").

SPJobdefinition does not allow me to do this as there is no lock type for server.

Shall I use the SPServerJobDefinition class to do this? If so, any sample code would help.

Comment: hi community, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace DotnetFinder
{
    class myTimerJobDef : SPServerJobDefinition
    {   
        public myTimerJobDef()

            : base()
        {

        }

        public myTimerJobDef(string jobName, SPServer server)

            : base(jobName, server)
        {
            this.Title = jobName;
        }


        public override void Execute(SPJobState _jobState)
        {

            Logs.LogMessage(Logs.Log_INFO, Logs.Log_severity_verbose, "Timer Job - Server specific is running on ");
        }
    }
}

        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            DotnetFinder.myTimerJobDef myJob = new DotnetFinder.myTimerJobDef("Server Timer Job", SPFarm.Local.Servers["myServer"]);
            // here you can assign the schedule as per your requirement. I have created a daily schedule

            SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule(); // create a daily schedule to run the timer job
            schedule.BeginHour = 1;
            schedule.EndHour = 2;

            myJob.Schedule = schedule;
            myJob.Update(); // assign the schedule to the timer job
        }
```